# No notifications in irssi for new private messages

Tags: ssh, putty, gnu-screen, irssi

My problem is that I get no notifications in irssi when receiving a new message: whether that be a private message, or just a message from a chan which isn't my current window.

I use two different setups to use irssi:

On my Mac

- With iTerm, mosh to server.example.com
- Relaunch my screen ("screen -dRR -U -T screen-256color")
- Open irssi in one of my screen windows

On my Win7:

- PuTTY to server.example.com
- Relaunch my screen ("screen -dRR -U -T screen-256color")
- Open irssi in one of my screen windows

Neither of these two methods show any kind of notification.

**I'ld like to have some kind of notification in irssi that another window received a message, not a beep or visual bell.**

[My irssi config is here](http://pastebin.com/qf1c215A)

[My screen config is here](http://pastebin.com/6FxpuzUw)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A friend just gave me the answer but doesn't have an account here.

In

```
statusbar = {
   default = {
     items = {
        act = { priority = "10"; } // missing line
     }
  }
}
```

Comment: Where are you setting this config?